# URL forwarding from one domain to another, keeping the parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, url, amazon-s3, dns

How do I configure my short domain to forward to my primary domain but persist the url path? For example...

`example.org/<keep-this>`  should redirect to  `example.com/<keep-this>`

At the moment, the url path is being thrown out, so I'm seeing this... `example.org/<keep-this>` redirects to `example.com`

Note: my primary domain is hosted and managed at AWS S3/CloudFont/Route-53.

The configuration for the distribution is as follows:

```
    "ETag": "<hidden>”,
    "DistributionConfig": {
        "CallerReference": "<hidden>",
        "Aliases": {
            "Quantity": 2,
            "Items": [
                "<hidden>",
                "www.<hidden>"
            ]
        },
        "DefaultRootObject": "index.html",
        "Origins": {
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Items": [
                {
                    "Id": "S3-<hidden>",
                    "DomainName": "<hidden>.s3.amazonaws.com",
                    "OriginPath": "",
                    "CustomHeaders": {
                        "Quantity": 0
                    },
                    "S3OriginConfig": {
                        "OriginAccessIdentity": ""
                    },
                    "ConnectionAttempts": 3,
                    "ConnectionTimeout": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        "OriginGroups": {
            "Quantity": 0
        },
        "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
            "TargetOriginId": "S3-<hidden>",
            "TrustedSigners": {
                "Enabled": false,
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https",
            "AllowedMethods": {
                "Quantity": 2,
                "Items": [
                    "HEAD",
                    "GET"
                ],
                "CachedMethods": {
                    "Quantity": 2,
                    "Items": [
                        "HEAD",
                        "GET"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "SmoothStreaming": false,
            "Compress": true,
            "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "FieldLevelEncryptionId": "",
            "CachePolicyId": "<hidden>"
        },
        "CacheBehaviors": {
            "Quantity": 0
        },
        "CustomErrorResponses": {
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Items": [
                {
                    "ErrorCode": 403,
                    "ResponsePagePath": "/error.html",
                    "ResponseCode": "404",
                    "ErrorCachingMinTTL": 60
                }
            ]
        },
        "Comment": "",
        "Logging": {
            "Enabled": false,
            "IncludeCookies": false,
            "Bucket": "",
            "Prefix": ""
        },
        "PriceClass": "PriceClass_All",
        "Enabled": true,
        "ViewerCertificate": {
            "ACMCertificateArn": "<hidden>",
            "SSLSupportMethod": "sni-only",
            "MinimumProtocolVersion": "TLSv1.2_2019",
            "Certificate": "<hidden>",
            "CertificateSource": "acm"
        },
        "Restrictions": {
            "GeoRestriction": {
                "RestrictionType": "none",
                "Quantity": 0
            }
        },
        "WebACLId": "",
        "HttpVersion": "http2",
        "IsIPV6Enabled": true
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your CloudFront configuration, including origins and behaviors. Please update your question with the output from [aws cloudfront get-distribution-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/get-distribution-config.html) (or, if you're using CloudFormation or Terraform, the resource definitions).

Comment: And are you talking about URL _parameters_ or _paths_? You say parameter, but your example shows a path.

Comment: Thanks for that distinction – just changed it from "parameters" to "path."

Comment: Thanks @Parsifal – just added the output per get-distribution-config – I hid anything that seemed potentially unique or sensitive with <hidden>, just to be sure I didn't do something dangerous!

Comment: If you want `example.org` to point to `example.com`, I think you could simply create a `CNAME` record in Route 53 for `example.org` that points to `example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately solved this problem in both S3 and CloudFront by following the instruction [here](https://blog.chrisdpeters.com/full-domain-redirects-s3-and-cloudfront/). This is what I did...

In S3...

1. Going to the example.org S3 bucket > "Properties" > "Static website hosting".
2. Selecting "Redirect requests"
3. For the "Target bucket or domain" field, specifying example.com
4. Keeping the Protocol field empty.

In CloudFront...

1. Choose the distribution > "Origin and Origin Groups"
2. Select and edit the distribution
3. Change the "Origin Domain Name" to the exact name specified in the S3 bucket > "Properties" > "Static website hosting" endpoint field. It looks like: `http://example.org.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com`
4. Remove the "Default Root Object" for the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from `example.org/<keep-this>` to `example.com/<keep-this>`, simply use [S3 routing rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects).

1. Create a bucket named `example.org`
2. Turn on "Static website hosting"
3. Set the redirection rule as follows

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
      <Redirect>
        <HostName>example.com</HostName>
      </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Since S3 static website hosting doesn't support HTTPS, if you need HTTPS, you should place a CloudFront distro in front of it.